# Getting confused with per-organization allocation

Tags: data-storage

I am reading Data and File Storage Limits - I saw

> Enterprise Edition organization with 600 users receives 1,211 GB of file storage, or 2 GB per user multiplied by 600 users plus an additional 11 GB.\

[Data and File Storage Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm)

Not able to understand what is plus an additional 11 GB, is this allotted to a single user of for whole organisation.

Comment: That would be a discount if you purchase 600 Salesforce ($125/u/m) users licenses. Well this is for all users and note that this is FILE STORAGE space.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani, so you mean Data Storage Allocation Per User License is 20 MB (for record saving only) and this 1,211 GB + 11 GB is only for file storage only not for record saving

Comment: yess. This is a point to be noted. Let me know if this is your answer, I will put it as answer. Unlimited has 120MB

Comment: so per user can only save up to 10 000 records - right. Is it possible to allocate more storage space to store records by reducing the file storage

Comment: No, File Storage and Data storage are independent.

Comment: Is their any fix for storing more than 10 000 records per user.

Comment: You can purchase more storage from Salesforce. Unlimited edition has 120 MB storage. Also minimum storage is 1 GB so user can store records upto 1GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of Comments in Question:

This applies to whole Organisation.

Data Storage Allocation Per User License is 20 MB (for record saving only) and this 1,200 GB + 11 GB is only for file storage only not for record saving.

**Is it possible to allocate more storage space to store records by reducing the file storage?**
Ans: No, File Storage and Data storage are independent.

**Is their any fix for storing more than 10 000 records per user?**
You can purchase more storage from Salesforce. Unlimited edition has 120 MB storage. Also minimum storage is 1 GB so user can store records upto 1GB.

> For example, a Professional Edition organization with 10 users
>   receives 1 GB because 10 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 200 MB,
>   which is less than the 1 GB minimum. A Professional Edition
>   organization with 100 users receives more than the 1 GB minimum
>   because 100 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 2,000 MB.

Answer (score 2):

The Additional 11GB is overall (complete organization) and not per User.
[image]